# BERTopic error on similarity_threshold_merging

Tags: python, bert-language-model

I am trying to reproduce the code here:
https://www.atoti.io/articles/topic-modeling-on-twitter-using-sentence-bert/

But when I arrive at the creation of the BERTopic model

```
# Create BERTopic model
topic_model = BERTopic(top_n_words=20,
                       n_gram_range=(1,2), 
                       calculate_probabilities=True,
                       umap_model= umap_model,
                       hdbscan_model=hdbscan_model,
                       similarity_threshold_merging=0.5,
                       verbose=True)
```

> it says `__init__()` got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'similarity_threshold_merging'

Answer (score 0):

The available parameters for [BERTopic](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/api/bertopic.html#bertopic._bertopic.BERTopic.__init__) are:

> __init__(self, language='english', top_n_words=10, n_gram_range=(1, 1), min_topic_size=10, nr_topics=None, low_memory=False,
> calculate_probabilities=False, diversity=None, seed_topic_list=None,
> embedding_model=None, umap_model=None, hdbscan_model=None,
> vectorizer_model=None, verbose=False) special ¶

Remove all the parameters which are not provided by BERTopic constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In the [article you reference](https://www.atoti.io/articles/topic-modeling-on-twitter-using-sentence-bert/), the author mentions adding functionality to BERTopic. You need to make the same modifications or remove the `similarity_threshold_merging` parameter.

> The Need For Additional Features
>
> To fit our use case, we slightly revisited this Sentence BERT based library to be able to:
>
> - Merge topics having a similarity above a user-defined threshold
> - Extract the most relevant documents associated with any given topic
>   The above features are missing from the original library.